# Leak come from around gutter

Tags: leak

[image]

I am experiencing a large leak around my gutter. I got the gutter recently replaced so it’s not the gutter itself. From the picture you can see there’s a large dark spot behind the gutter on the corner. It was clearly caulked a lot before we moved in. That is where the leaking is coming from. If a gutter replacement isn’t fixing that, is that a job for a siding/roofing company? Let me know what my next move should be. Thanks.

Comment: Can't tell from the picture...do the shingles overlap the gutter there? They need to overlap a little bit.

Comment: Yeah, I can't be sure from this gritty image, but I don't see drip edge. In fact it looks like something's missing at the lower foot or so of the rake.